# If for each setter I can get the blockchain state at the moment and make it queryable, will I still need events?

Tags: events

That question came as part of understanding better the role of events in Ethereum.

Can the mechanism which index the blockchain state at each setter and makes it queryable for all parties can replace the need for emitting events?

The only reason I can think of is to eliminate the trust of the party who manages that indexing and make it queryable.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a contract is generally immutable so it is appropriate to aim for a comprehensive solution that will accommodate client-side requirements not anticipated at this time. In this context, a "client" can be another contract, a user, a server, or something else--everything external to the contract.

There is more than one approach. The following is the most common and a good starting point.

1. Ensure the current contract state is completely discoverable. Clients and other contracts can explore the *current* state with `view` functions.
2. The state *history* can be completely reconstructed from event logs. That is, a client can discover all inputs to all state-changing functions (in order) from event logs and if it wants to, compute the state at any point in time up to the present moment.

That combination gives clients options. They can, for example, inspect the current state and then listen to logs for changes. Or, a client can listen exclusively to event logs and always work out what the state *must be*. Or, a client that is interested in the current state of something can simply inspect a function. You might say the contract is agnostic about how the clients inspect it.

There are only two things to remember as you build a contract:

1. Ensure all variables are `public` or build your own getter functions for `private` variables.
2. Emit an event for every state change. Event logs should closely correspond to function *inputs* but they can include extra data if useful. This is one area where it's okay to be *a little* courteous to clients, but don't get carried away. Gas costs add up and given the *inputs*, clients can *always* figure things out for themselves.

That pattern covers most cases.

Astute readers will have noticed that if the "client" is another contract, then it won't be able to reconstruct past states or read the history because event logs are off-limits to other contracts. That is generally okay because other contracts are *usually* only interested in the current state.

Since contract state data is *much more expensive* than event log data it is worth carefully considering and trying to find a way around any *perceived need* to make history explorable by other contracts. For emphasis, other contracts seldom have any logical requirement to explore past states.

Start with the pattern described and if it doesn't seem to cover everything or seems to have unnecessary parts, construct a strong logical justification for adding something else, or removing something that is usually there. Always keep in mind that it has to be acceptable in all cases, forever.

Hope it helps.